# Lower div deforms in CSS and jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a Day & Night cycle animation with jQuery, CSS and Html.

When I run the animation by clicking the slider below, the water portion which is like a semi-circle in the bottom half of the large circle, deforms into a rectangle.

Here is the code on JsFiddle for my Day & Night cycle animation:
[https:// jsfiddle.net/g0Lpzfqr/3/](https://%20jsfiddle.net/g0Lpzfqr/3/)

Comment: Your time-circle was smaller than other elements I changed its width and height to match other elements. You can see its working now. If you want any other solution, do comment so we can better help you

Comment: You should try one of freely available good WYSIWYG (what you see is what you get) editor  for your css and html code to prevent such problems. http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/top-css-editors-reviewed/

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your CSS code. The water Div is smaller thats why it deforms during animation. You can either:

- increase the height and width of the only the smaller time-circle  in CSS to make it larger and match other larger elements.

Or

- You can decrease the height and width of all other elements to match the smaller time-circle

If you want an easier solution then you should change the width and height of the .time-circle from 200px to 400px in your CSS code as below:

```
.time-circle {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;

}
```

Check your edited Jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ydus80wp/3/
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this problem by using `z-index` .
Add `z-index: 0;` to your water class.

check this fiddle out: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Naderial/qnjumLqc/